# How to fix my results are overwritten with tensorflow and matplotlib?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow to analyze some images, but when I run the program the images are overwritten and I don't know how to fix it, I should see several images as a result, but only one image appears that is being overwritten over and over again

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
import json
import time
import glob
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
from utils import label_map_util
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import argparse, sys


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--labels', help='Directorio a label_map.pbtxt', default ='D:/Downloads/deteccion_objetos-master/deteccion_objetos-master/configuracion/label_map.pbtxt')
parser.add_argument('--images', help='Directorio de las imagenes a procesar', default = 'D:/Downloads/deteccion_objetos-master/deteccion_objetos-master/img_pruebas')
parser.add_argument('--model', help='Directorio al modelo congelado', default = 'D:/Downloads/deteccion_objetos-master/deteccion_objetos-master/modelo_congelado')
args = parser.parse_args()

MAX_NUMBER_OF_BOXES = 30
MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE = 0.4

PATH_TO_LABELS = args.labels
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = args.images

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=sys.maxsize, use_display_name=True)
CATEGORY_INDEX = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
MODEL_NAME = args.model
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
    (im_width, im_height) = image.size
    return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
        (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

def detect_objects(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)

    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run([detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections], feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        CATEGORY_INDEX,
        min_score_thresh=MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8)
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)
    ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
    ax.set_axis_off()
    fig.add_axes(ax)

    plt.imshow(image_np, aspect = 'auto')
    plt.savefig('D:/Downloads/deteccion_objetos-master/deteccion_objetos-master/output/img_pruebas/img_pruebas'.format(image_path), dpi = 62)
    print(boxes)
    plt.close(fig)

# TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image-{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 4) ]
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = glob.glob(os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, '*.jpeg'))
print(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)

# Load model into memory
print('Loading model...')
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

print('detecting...')
with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

        for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
            detect_objects(image_path)
```

As a result, many different images should appear but instead the images that are being overwritten appear as a loop until I finish analyzing the images

Answer (score 1):

You should adapt your line

```
 plt.savefig('D:/Downloads/deteccion_objetos-master/deteccion_objetos-master/output/img_pruebas/img_pruebas'.format(image_path), dpi = 62)
```

Now, whatever the value of `image_path` is, the plot is always created at `D:/Downloads/deteccion_objetos-master/deteccion_objetos-master/output/img_pruebas/img_pruebas`.

You probably want something like:

```
import os

plt.savefig('D:/Downloads/deteccion_objetos-master/deteccion_objetos-master/output/img_pruebas/img_pruebas/{}'.format(os.path.basename(image_path)))
```

Comment: Hi @BioGeek, 
I just made the modification that you mentioned but I get an error I attach it to you in the same forum here as another answer, how could I fix that error?

Comment: Forget it and I managed to solve it, thank you very much for your help!